# Cross Domain Ajax fail - parseerror as callback not called

Tags: jquery, ajax, cross-domain, jsonp

I have set a `ajax` which need to cross domain, some of the *API* work without any error, but some return `parserror`.
I can't figure it out why this happened and how to solve it, hope anyone can give me some direction, thanks.

Here is my code:

```
// After OAuth2 to get the token
$.ajaxSetup({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    statusCode: {
        401: function() {
            window.open('page for oauth2');
        }
    }
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://redbooth.com/api/3/me',         // this one work without problem
    method: 'GET'
})
.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    alert('success');
});

$.ajax({
    url: 'https://redbooth.com/api/3/projects?order=id&archived=false',
    method: 'GET'
})
.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    alert('test');
})
.fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
    // this API will throw error
    // jqXHR: status = 200, readyState = 4, statusText = "load"
    // textStatus: parserror
    // errorThrown: xxx was not called
    var test = 1;
});
```

I have checked the return value from their console and also in fiddler:

> [{"type":"Project","created_at":0,"updated_at":0,"id":0,"permalink":"test-1cc1c3","organization_id":0,"archived":false,"name":"test","description":null,"start_date":null,"end_date":null,"tracks_time":false,"public":true,"publish_pages":false,"settings":{},"user_id":0,"deleted":false,"last_goal_user_id":0}]

*Please note I have modified the value here, just replace those id with 0*

I tried to validate the return value in *JSON validator* or use `$.parseJSON('return value')`, both can return the JSON object without issue.

I have tried following:
- [I am getting a json parse error on a cross-domain ajax call not sure how to get rid of the issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353871/i-am-getting-a-json-parse-error-on-a-cross-domain-ajax-call-not-sure-how-to-get)
- set `'jsonp': false`
- set `'dataType': 'text'`, result in cross-origin issue
- set `'dataType':'text,'crossDomain':true`, still cross-origin issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if jsonp is not working you can try calling the url from server instead trying from javascript/ajax.

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'proxy.php',
    data: {url :'https://redbooth.com/api/3/projects?order=id&archived=false'},
    method: 'GET'
})
.done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
    alert('test');
})
```

**proxy.php**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['url']) and !empty($_POST['url'])) {
$data = file_get_contents($_POST['url']);
print $data;
}
?>
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid it if it is possible

Comment: It good practice to avoid the server intervention but for cross domain issues, I suggest you go with the server side triggering. Hope this helps you.